# memory efficient storage of set of integers for java

Tags: java, data-structures

I would like to store a set of integers efficiently. HashSet in Java is not so efficient in term of memory usage because of the wrapper class. Sorted array of integers would loose the amortized constant time look up. I also need to iterate through each element so BitSet is not great as well.

Comment: Do you have hard evidence that using a `HashSet<Integer>` is a problem for your application?

Comment: if hashset uses primitive type not the wrapper class, then it is memory efficient but it did not.

Comment: I know. From a memory usage perspective, `HashSet<Integer>` is appalling. Not just because it uses `Integer` rather than `int`, but also because it's backed by a `HashMap`, so every entry has a completely useless value field. There are loads of libraries for primitive collections out there, but unless you are sure that HashSet is not an option, I would stick to the most familiar class.

Comment: Right now, a reduced factor of 10 would be savior for me :). Which are those libraries ? You know which one is also clearly more efficient than others ?

Comment: putting the title of this post into google provides a whole bunch of hits with relevant libraries...

Comment: I did and I got many libraries Trove, SparseArray, Apache Integer Hash Set but confuses me more. If you could point to a post that compares those libraries, that would be super helpful.

Comment: @BenjaminNguyen I've never used any of them, I'm afraid. I don't know how reliable this is https://dzone.com/articles/time-memory-tradeoff-example

Comment: BitSet is perfectly fine for iterating over integers if the elements are all relatively small and dense; you just use nextSetBit.

Comment: Awesome. This is a really good start for me.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions. An excessive number of poorly received questions that are off-topic will get you banned from asking questions, and you do not want that do you?

Answer (score 0):

The widely-used GNU Trove library provides a lot of excellent primitive-type collections

http://trove.starlight-systems.com/

https://bitbucket.org/trove4j/trove

Comment: do not answer recommendations questions, and especially not with link only answers